# Same punishement for man that cheats on his wife than for woman that cheats on husband?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, cheating

First : are there Quran verses that mentionned some punishement and that is bad to cheat ?

And if yes, is there diference between a woman cheater or man cheater ?

Comment: First yes: read the beginning of surat an-Nur. Second no there's no difference.